# Быстрое прописывание конструкций языка VS C++

Tags: visual-studio-2017

На данный момент работаю в Visual Studio C++ 2017. Можно ли как-то в редакторе быстрее прописывать базовые конструкции языка? Например, написал в своем коде "for ++i n", он мне развернул в

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){

}
```

P.S. Понятия не имею как этот маневр называется, объяснил как мог. Если все же можно, расскажите, что это такое и работает ли в других редакторах Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно. Для этого существуют Code Snippets. Допустим, для цикла for вы можете начать вводить `for` и студия автоматически предложит его вам.[image: VS Snippets]

Это создаст вам подобный шаблон:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Заведите себе закомментированные куски кода и делайте copy-past. Типа такого:

```
/*

for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){

}

*/
```

Comment: VS не умеет такие простые вещи делать, кроме как копипаста???